# How to send programmatically encrypted email using Azure Information protection C#

Tags: c#, smtp, azure-information-protection, o365security-compliance

I would like to send encrypted emails through console application built in C#. My org has AIP implemented and would like to leverage either sensitivity labels or AIP, I tried adding sensitivity using headers as Company-Confidential but it does not solve my purpose as I want to encrypt and make email protected.
Please suggest if there is any way to encrypt email or apply custom sensitivity label as protected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at the MIP SDK.

https://aka.ms/mipsdkdocs
https://aka.ms/mipsdksamples